# Integrate HP ALM with Informatica DVO

Tags: informatica-powercenter, alm, application-lifecycle, hp-alm

Is there a way to integrate ALM with Informatica DVO? I am writing my tests in DVO but want to do test execution and reporting via ALM. Is that possible?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named “What topics can I ask about here?” and “What types of questions should I avoid asking?”. And more importantly, please read the Stack Overflow question checklist. You might also want to learn about Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can represent other type of tests in HPE ALM as [VAPI-XP Tests](https://almmsi.saas.hpe.com/qcbin/Help/doc_library/online_help/Content/UG/menu_vapi_xp.htm).
With the help of the OTA API; you could automate the upload, configuration and other activities related to your tests. In the background it will execute a VBScript and as a content of the script you could call your own test engine.

The content of the script should be universal (All scripts should have the same content, and the test case name / path should be the only variable.) - it should be only about calling your test robot.